# How can i add an image to a RecyclerView within the AdapterClass?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

Here is the Product bean class [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQyDV.png)

So my Recycle view is working but this line of code hasn't worked.This is from My Adapter Class.

```
holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(mCtx.getResources().getDrawable(product.getImage()));
```

CLASS

```
@NonNull
@Override
public productViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout,null);
    productViewHolder holder = new productViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
    //  return new productViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull productViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Product product = productList.get(position);
    holder.textViewTitle.setText(product.getTitle());
    holder.textViewDescription.setText(product.getShort_description());
    holder.textViewRating.setText(String.valueOf(product.getRating()));
    holder.textViewPrice.setText(String.valueOf(product.getPrice()));

//    holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(mCtx.getResources().getDrawable(product.getImage()));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    //returns number of elements within the list
    return productList.size();
}

class productViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textViewTitle, textViewDescription, textViewRating, textViewPrice;


    public productViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
        textViewDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewShortDesc);
        textViewRating = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRating);
        textViewPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPrice);
    }
```

Comment: what is `product.getImage()`?

Comment: public Product(int id, String title, String short_description, Double rating, Double price, int image)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.short_description = short_description;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.price = price;
        this.image = image;


    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

Comment: sorry for how cionfusing it may look, can i send images here ?

Comment: can i send an image over twitter?

Comment: ok, how do you set the `Product`? Specifically, how do you get the Image to bet set in `Product`?

Comment: Just share it here (or update the question with additional data/asked data)

Comment: i didnt know how i sent a twitter image. I apologize i am quite new

Comment: no need to apologize. Just show us the code where you set the `Product` variable.

Comment: i upload image above

Comment: by calling with get

Answer (score 0):

If your image in product object contains image resource from your drawable package then you need to use

```
holder.imageView.setImageResource(product.getImage());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**if you getting the data form api set the image like this**

```
 RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
            .centerCrop()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.avatar1)
            .error(R.drawable.avatar1)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .priority(Priority.HIGH)
            .dontAnimate()
            .dontTransform();

 Glide.with(context)
            .load(UpcomingHistoryList.get(position).getPhotoUrl())
            .apply(options)
            .into(holder.img);
```

**you can use glide and picasso**

**if you getting the image form drawable set the image like this**

```
  ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
  imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.hello);
```

Comment: all files are in txt. May you have a look

Answer (score 0):

I think you get a String of Your product object, you should try to convert that estring to Uri or bitmap so that when you make a set in the imageview then you can show, it would help a lot if you show your product class to know what type of value returns product.getimage();
 `Uri.parse(product.getImage());`

Comment: The classes and layouts are here

Comment: The thing is when i remove holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(mCtx.getResources().getDrawable(product.getImage()));
The list shows ,but when i add this to the adapter class the entire app wont run

Comment: ok, but do you want to show a loaded image of your phone or the drawable folder?,ok, but you want to show a loaded image of your phone or the drawable folder ?, can you send screenshot of the error? I suppose it's going to be, an error null pointer exception

Comment: from the drawable folder

Comment: ok, use a git library     in gradle.app  .......  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'                                                                          luego  Glide.with(context)
                .load(//produc.getimage)
                .fitCenter()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.imageview);

Comment: which one are you thinking of specifically

Comment: There is a method that I use to load drawable files, they are vector isset

Answer (score 0):

There is a method that I use to load drawable files, they are vector isset

```
 public static BitmapDescriptor getBitmapFromVector(@NonNull Context context,
                                                   @DrawableRes int vectorResourceId,
                                                   @ColorInt int tintColor) {

    Drawable vectorDrawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(
            context.getResources(), vectorResourceId, null);
    if (vectorDrawable == null) {
        String TAG = "tag";
        Log.e(TAG, "Requested vector resource was not found");
        return BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker();
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
            vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    DrawableCompat.setTint(vectorDrawable, tintColor);
    vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
    return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

after that, it only remains   imageview.setImageBitmap(Bitmapdescriptor(parameters);

Answer (score 0):

By reading comments it looks like your product object stores image as a string. The getImage() method must return int.

Declare image(with some default image)  in Product as follows :

```
private int image = R.drawable.default_image;
```

And the getter will look like this

```
public int getImage() {
  return image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Object class for Product

class Product{

        public Product(String title, String short_description, double rating, double price, int image) {
            this.title = title;
            this.short_description = short_description;
            this.rating = rating;
            this.price = price;
            this.image = image;
        }

        String title;
        String short_description;
        double rating;
        double price;
        int image;
    }


    //Array List of products
    List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
          productList.add(new Product("Title1", "Short Description1", 4, 50, R.drawable.ic_thumb_down));
        productList.add(new Product("Title2", "Short Description2", 3, 100, R.drawable.ic_thumb_down));
        productList.add(new Product("Title3", "Short Description3", 4, 150, R.drawable.ic_thumb_down));




    //Adapter

        public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ImageViewHolder>{

            List<Integer> resourceList;

            public ImageAdapter(List<Integer> resourceList) {
                this.resourceList = resourceList;
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                return new ImageViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_image, viewGroup, false));
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageViewHolder imageViewHolder, int i) {


              Product product = productList.get(i);
              imageViewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(product.image);
              // Here you can also use other field like title, description, etc... 

            }

            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return resourceList.size();
            }

            class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

                ImageView imageView;

                public ImageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                    super(itemView);
                    imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: could i replace the Int in the array to Product? My class

Comment: Yes. you can use any object for array.

Comment: @D-TECK Updated answer. used array of products as you need.

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompact.getDrawable(ctxt, R.drawable.YOUR_RESOURCE_IMAGE));
```

if your product.getimage() returns a resource id which is R.drwable.YOUR_RESOURCE_IMAGE
try using:

```
  holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompact.getDrawable(ctxt, product.getimage()));
```